# Why does LINQ.Sum<Nullable<T>> return <Nullable<T>> ? When would LINQ.Sum return null?

Tags: c#, linq, sum, nullable

Came across a scenario where had to do a sum on a nullable decimal list, and then we had to validate against null, because CA warnings and whatnot. The author of the code said that the sum is never 0, that's why he/she didn't put a check in place.

Thinking of it, I haven't found a reason for why list.Sum returns a `decimal?` type in stead of 'decimal'

Any thoughts on the reasoning behind the signature and/or how to handle this situation ? (I could put null-coalescing to return only decimal, but feels like a hack)

And to also have a little code, these were my attempts to get null:

```
var case1 = (new List<decimal?> { }).Sum();
var case2 = (new List<decimal?> { null, null }).Sum();
```

Comment: `Sum<X>(...)` returns `X`. Period. That's how it is declared, that's what it does. I agree that it could've returned just `decimal`, but someone decided it shouldn't. `X` here is not `T`, because there is no such method, but there are specific methods for each of the numeric types, and the nullable versions return nullable.

Comment: Note that with `Queryable.Sum` it is different... Imagine this query: `SELECT SUM(X) FROM (SELECT 1 X WHERE 1 = 0) Base`, so a `SELECT SUM()` over an empty table. The result is `NULL`.

Comment: `Sum<decimal?>` is a *specific* extension method that will never return `null`, so I fully understand the question, but they still decided to declare it as returning `decimal?`.

Comment: @xanatos: there is no `Enumerable.Sum(IEnumerable<T>)`. All overloads of `Sum` exist for specific types. The versions that take an `IEnumerable<T>` also take a function mapping the input to one of these specific types, and they don't return `T`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: what `xanatos` meant is that `IQueryable<Nullable<T>>.Sum()` *can* return `null`.

Comment: @Groo: that would make sense, if not for the fact that in the query referenced, `X` is not a nullable column, and you'd be querying over an `IQueryable<int>`. The LINQ methods are explicitly documented as returning `0` when their sequences are empty; the fact that a database yields `NULL` in such a case is another thing. (It may be done this way so that providers can choose to use nullable types in this case to account for the fact that the database can always return `NULL`, even if the expressions involved are non-nullable. You do have to explicitly choose for it then, though.)

Comment: for further clarification: we're not talking about
`public static Nullable<decimal> Sum (this System.Linq.IQueryable<Nullable<decimal>> source);`
but about
`public static Nullable<decimal> Sum(this IEnumerable<Nullable<decimal>> source)` (edited formatting)

Comment: strangest thing is that the Enumerable.Sum method for `decimal?` actually computes a `decimal`, that casts to `decimal?` on return... so this was a design decision (but still don't understand the logic behind it)

Comment: @JeroenMostert When you say *LINQ methods*, what do you mean? Both `Enumerable` and `Queryable` are part of `System.Linq` and *are* considered LINQ. Both has `Sum<decimal?>` method with different documentation (for  `Queryable` it's funny - *"...depends on the implementation of the type of the source parameter. The expected behavior is that it returns the sum of the values in source."*). The `Enumerable` implementation always returning 0 (documented or not) is wrong for me, but there is nothing we can do.

Comment: @IvanStoev we can start a revolution !! or we can wait for C#8

Comment: @IvanStoev: Allowing query providers to return `null` when nullable types are summed is probably the motivation, then -- even though, ironically or otherwise, the most common providers don't actually do this. (SQL Server will happily ignore `NULL` values in summation, for example, even though the "logical" thing to do would be to give `NULL` if any value in the sequence is `NULL`.)

Comment: @norb: I'd say it's probably the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). If `Min`, `Max` or `Average` all return the source type, and there is also a generic version of all these methods which returns `T`, it would be awkward if they changed the return type for a specific method based on an implementation detail. You could then argue that `Math.Floor(double)` should return `int` instead of `double` (perhaps a bit contrived example, but you get the idea).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Actually all standard SQL implementations return `NULL` when (A) the sequence has not records and (B) when **all** values are `NULL`.

Comment: @Groo: `Math.Floor(2147483649.56)` won't fit in an `int`, so not the best example. But usually you'd expect input type to match output type, yes.

Comment: @IvanStoev: right! All values being `NULL` is actually the much better use case (compared to the empty sequence), and I'd say it explains why `Sum` over nullables must return a nullable itself.

Comment: @JeroenMostert That's the case in SQL (and prolly IQueryable) but in Enumerable.Sum the _return null when_ case was omitted (btw, these were the two examples from the original post). If they would have adhered to the SQL standard implementation on this, then this question wouldn't have existed...

Comment: Yes, but it's fairly obvious that `Enumerable.Sum` and `Queryable.Sum` ought to have the same signatures, once you have decided on one. LINQ to Objects is supposed to be just one implementation of the more general pattern. I can't immediately think up a use case where it would actively cause trouble for `Enumerable.Sum` to have a more restrictive return type, but I'm pretty sure that's just my poverty of imagination. Whether it was a good idea for `Enumerable.Sum` to always return `0` is, as others have debated, debatable, but it's not prohibited by the general spec either.

Comment: _it's fairly obvious that Enumerable.Sum and Queryable.Sum ought to have the same signatures_ ; this is not that obvious for me. Obvious is that similar methods from the _same class_ should return similar types (like Sum, Avg, Prod)

Comment: Going from `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable` and back is very easy (as it ought to be, as LINQ to Object is just another LINQ provider). Consider that you're arguing that `x.Sum()` and `x.AsEnumerable().Sum()` should return different types if `x` is `IQueryable<int?>`. This is, at the very least, slightly unintuitive. Don't get hung up by the fact that the extension methods live in classes; this is almost uninteresting as far as their usage is concerned.

Comment: _Going from IQueryable to IEnumerable and back is very easy_ because inheritance and stuff like that. Taking your point, consider that you expect x.Sum() and x.AsEnumerable().Sum() to return the same type, you should expect to return the same result, right ? You could easily introduce a very subtle bug in your system this way...  (edit: I think we're starting to go a little off-topic here)

Comment: I agree -- it is going off-topic and I think there's enough material in the comments to essentially cobble together an answer, for anyone so inclined. Debating the merits of the decision is then best left for another forum. :-)

Comment: It makes me think about the unfortunate different in `null` handling with column (property) references between `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable` that I wish didn't exist. In places where `IQueryable` will accept e.g. `a.SomeProp` you must use `a?.SomeProp` for an `IEnumerable` query.